# Readline split by anything else than letters

Tags: c#, split, readline

How do I use the `Console.Readline().Split()` to split anything else than letters(, * & % .). Instead of inputting every one of the possible characters in the `Split()`, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] segments = Regex.Split(input: line, pattern: "\W");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split takes `params` which means the parameter list is turned into an array argument.

You can pass in a list of strings to split by - for example, with the characters you have given:

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
var segements = line.Split(' ', ',', '*', '&', '%', '.');
```

Edit: The regular expression answers are good, if thats what you mean - but if you only want the specified characters then this is better - because it wont be affected by non-English characters.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Readline()` return String, so use the `Split` is just like usual [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

You can use Split with regex